# how can I position the image at the left of the div inside my header?

Tags: html, css, image, header, positioning

so here is my problem. I have managed to put the image which is the logo at the left hand side of the header for both tablet and mobile version, however when I display it in the desktop version the logo is the left but not in the corner like I want it. I tried putting a right margin to it, but I think there is a better way to do it instead of doing that. the same thing happens with my ul list. it's in the right corner on both tablet and mobile but it is not in the desktop version. this is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat|Cardo' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>

.main_h {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  max-height: 70px;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 17px;
  background: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  opacity: 0;
  top: -100px;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 766px) {
  .main_h {
    padding-top: 25px;
  }
}

.open-nav {
  max-height: 400px !important;
}
.open-nav .mobile-toggle {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.sticky {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.93);
  opacity: 1;
  top: 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gainsboro;
}

.logo {
  width: 150px;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #8f8f8f;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 766px) {
  .logo {
    float: none;
  }
}

nav {
  float: right;
  width: 60%;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 766px) {
  nav {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
  
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 766px) {
  nav ul {
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 22px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 35px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  text-align: center;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 766px) {
  nav ul li {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 7px 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
nav ul a {
  color: #000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}

.mobile-toggle {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 22px;
  top: 0;
  width: 30px;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 766px) {
  .mobile-toggle {
    display: block;
  }
}
.mobile-toggle span {
  width: 30px;
  height: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  border-radius: 1000px;
  background: #8f8f8f;
  display: block;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 940px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 2%;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  color: #8f8f8f;
  background: white;
  font-family: "Cardo", serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 1.8;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}

p {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 2;
}

.content {
  padding: 50px 2% 250px;
}

.hero {
  position: relative;
  background: url(http://www.philippefercha.com/cd/toggle-menu-bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 110px;
  min-height: 500px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}
.hero h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 1.3;
}
.hero h1 span {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #e8f380;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #e8f380;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  line-height: 3;
}

.mouse {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 26px;
  height: 46px;
  border-radius: 13px;
  border: 2px solid #e8f380;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -26px;
}
.mouse span {
  display: block;
  margin: 6px auto;
  width: 2px;
  height: 2px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #e8f380;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-name: scroll;
  animation-name: scroll;
}

@-webkit-keyframes scroll {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(20px);
    transform: translateY(20px);
  }
}
@keyframes scroll {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(20px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(20px);
    transform: translateY(20px);
  }
}


</style>



<body>
  
<header class="main_h">

    <div class="row">
        <img src = "logo.png" class="logo" href="#"></a>

        <div class="mobile-toggle">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
        </div>

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href=".sec01">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href=".sec02">Abous Us</a></li>
                <li><a href=".sec03">Contact Us</a></li>
                
            </ul>
        </nav>

    </div> <!-- / row -->

</header>



<script>
// Sticky Header
$(window).scroll(function() {

    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('.main_h').addClass('sticky');
    } else {
        $('.main_h').removeClass('sticky');
    }
});

// Mobile Navigation
$('.mobile-toggle').click(function() {
    if ($('.main_h').hasClass('open-nav')) {
        $('.main_h').removeClass('open-nav');
    } else {
        $('.main_h').addClass('open-nav');
    }
});

$('.main_h li a').click(function() {
    if ($('.main_h').hasClass('open-nav')) {
        $('.navigation').removeClass('open-nav');
        $('.main_h').removeClass('open-nav');
    }
});

// navigation scroll lijepo radi materem
$('nav a').click(function(event) {
    var id = $(this).attr("href");
    var offset = 70;
    var target = $(id).offset().top - offset;
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: target
    }, 500);
    event.preventDefault();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your code snippet displays nothing, its better if you edit your code and present it in more suer friendly way

Comment: I found out it is the max-width i had in the .row

Answer (score 0):

sorry to tell you that but I don't like your CSS, and opacity 0 on the entire page? float everywhere, I don't get it ^^ first of all try to put CSS in a CSS file and JS in a JS file

I did not understand what the span things were for, I removed them for the structure

now for the code

I can recommend using a structure, would be easier

something like this:

HTML:

```css
body{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.col1x3{
    width: 33%;
}

.col1x2{
  width: 50%;
}

.element{
  margin-right: -0.25em;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="element col1x2">
      <img src = "https://www.magknit.co.uk/staging/1365/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/descarga-1-1.png" class="logo" href="#"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="element col1x2">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li class="element col1x3"><a href=".sec01">Home</a></li>
          <li class="element col1x3"><a href=".sec02">Abous Us</a></li>
          <li class="element col1x3"><a href=".sec03">Contact Us</a></li>

        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out it is the max-width in the .row that is causing the problem. i had it set up to 960px so the row would not be longer than that. I just had to set it to whatever screen size I wanted and that is it.